# Replace result from awk

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, awk

Basically, what I want to do is replacing a result parsed from awk with something else.
I have the following awk command :

`awk '$1~/^DocumentRoot/{print $2}' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

Which returns :

`/var/www/`

What I want to do is replace the `/var/www/` (of course, it can be anything and not /var/www/ in particular) in the file. I tried to pipe a sed command, but I can't figure out how to do it...

Anyone can help ?

Comment: I want to replace it with anything like :
`/var/www2` or any path I'll pass on the command line.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said before, the file is like this :
`DocumentRoot /var/www`
But it also can be like :
`DocumentRoot /usr/www/`

So the path can be anything. That's why I used awk to get what's after the "DocumentRoot" word.

Comment: Could you give an example result please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch the result in the `text` variable and then `sed -i` it.

```
text=$(awk '$1~/^DocumentRoot/{print $2}' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default)
sed -i "s#$text##g" /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

Based on your comment

> the file is like this : DocumentRoot /var/www But it also can be like
>   : DocumentRoot /usr/www/

You can do everything with sed:

```
$ cat a
DocumentRoot /var/www
eee
$ sed -i 's#DocumentRoot.*#DocumentRoot hello#g' a
$ cat a
DocumentRoot hello
eee
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to replace `/var/www/` by something else, let's say `/var/www2/` and display the path modified.
If this is the case go for

```
awk '$1~/^DocumentRoot/{print $2="/var/log/"; print;}' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```